# Customer Display make text scroll using HEX code

Tags: c#, serial-port, hex

i need help on scrolling the text using C# on customer pole display COM 5. I have tried some hexcodes like moving the cursor or blinking the display but cannot figure out how to make the text scroll on the display
[List of hexcodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jij3.jpg)

[list of hexcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWDyA.jpg)

```
            //To Make the Display blink
            byte[] byteSelfTest = new byte[3] { 0x1F,0x45,0x05 };
            port.Write(byteInitializeDisplay, 0, byteInitializeDisplay.Length);
```

Comment: What do you mean by scroll?  If the display only has two lines, when the user 'scrolls down' you just overwrite the two lines with the next two lines (usually with a keypad).  Generally you can put arrow ascii to let the user know there is more available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no function for specifying the number of digits or the number of lines to scroll the contents currently displayed in the materials you presented.

You can scroll out existing data when writing data exceeding the screen size after changing mode with US MD2 or US MD3 control code.

It is done automatically by the relation between the scroll mode at that time and the data size written additionally.

Comment: so you are saying whenever i pass a string to the display and send the hexcode after that, if the string length is more than the display...it will autoscroll?

Comment: According to the content of the document, I think that it will auto scroll.

Comment: i have tried and able to scroll, but it scrolls way too fast.Anyway to make it scroll horizontally slower

Comment: Since the function to control the display timing is not described, it is necessary to devise it by the application itself. Writing the characters to be displayed one by one separately, it will be processing such as putting delay by sleep during that.

Comment: Thank you very much. Im able to solve my issue with the suggestions you gave.Once again thank you very much